# How to make JSON from SQL query in MS SQL 2014

Tags: sql, json, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Question: What is best solution to generate JSON from a SQL query in MS SQL 2014? I created a procedure, but it is very slow.

My Example:

```
DECLARE @customers xml;
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max);
SET @customers  =  (SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers FOR XML path, root)
EXEC [dbo].[HTTP_JSON]  @customers, @json

EXEC [dbo].[HTTP_JSON](@Shopping)

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[HTTP_JSON]
@parameters xml, @response NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
set @response = (SELECT Stuff(  
  (SELECT * from  
    (SELECT ',
    {'+  
      Stuff((SELECT ',"'+coalesce(b.c.value('local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),'')+'":"'+
                    b.c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') +'"'

             from x.a.nodes('*') b(c)  
             for xml path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')+'}' 
   from @parameters.nodes('/root/*') x(a)  
   ) JSON(theLine)  
  for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)' )
,1,1,''))
GO
```

Comment: With SQL Server 2016 there is native JSON support... For this question you do not provide enough details: Please show your input. Provide an example of `@parameters` and provide the expected output (example of a valid JSON built with the actual data from `@parameters`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just for fun, I created a scalar function based off of my prior answer.

Aside from the obvious XML parameter, I added two additional: 1) Include Header (illustrated below), and 2) ToLower case (I prefer my JSON field names in lower case which links to my classes and such).

If the query is more than one record, a formatted array will be returned.

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com'),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select A.ID
      ,A.Last_Name
      ,A.First_Name
      ,B.JSON
From  @Table A 
Cross Apply (Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select A.* For XML Raw)) ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Last_Name   First_Name  JSON
1   Smith       John        {"id":"1","active":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","email":"john.smith@email.com"}
2   Doe         Jane        {"id":"2","active":"0","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","email":"jane.doe@email.com"}
```

**Or even more simply**

```
Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select * From @Table for XML RAW))
```

**Returns with Header ON**

```
{
    "status": {
        "successful": "true",
        "timestamp": "2016-10-09 06:08:16 GMT",
        "rows": "2"
    },
    "results": [{
        "id": "1",
        "active": "1",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "john.smith@email.com"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "active": "0",
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "jane.doe@email.com"
    }]
}
```

**Returns with Header Off**

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "active": "1",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@email.com"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "active": "0",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "email": "jane.doe@email.com"
}]
```

**The UDF**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-JSON] (@IncludeHead int,@ToLowerCase int,@XML xml)
Returns varchar(max)
AS
Begin
    Declare @Head varchar(max) = '',@JSON varchar(max) = ''
    ; with cteEAV as (Select RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
                            ,Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(100)')
                            ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                            ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                       From  @XML.nodes('/row') As R(xRow) 
                       Cross Apply R.xRow.nodes('./@*') As A(xAtt) )
          ,cteSum as (Select Records=count(Distinct Entity)
                            ,Head = IIF(@IncludeHead=0,IIF(count(Distinct Entity)<=1,'[getResults]','[[getResults]]'),Concat('{"status":{"successful":"true","timestamp":"',Format(GetUTCDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss '),'GMT','","rows":"',count(Distinct Entity),'"},"results":[[getResults]]}') ) 
                       From  cteEAV)
          ,cteBld as (Select *
                            ,NewRow=IIF(Lag(Entity,1)  over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,'',',{')
                            ,EndRow=IIF(Lead(Entity,1) over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,',','}')
                            ,JSON=Concat('"',IIF(@ToLowerCase=1,Lower(Attribute),Attribute),'":','"',Value,'"') 
                       From  cteEAV )
    Select @JSON = @JSON+NewRow+JSON+EndRow,@Head = Head From cteBld, cteSum
    Return Replace(@Head,'[getResults]',Stuff(@JSON,1,1,''))
End
-- Parameter 1: @IncludeHead 1/0
-- Parameter 2: @ToLowerCase 1/0 (converts field name to lowercase
-- Parameter 3: (Select * From ... for XML RAW)
```

**EDIT - Corrected Typo

Comment: It's not working if I use `as` key . Query : `Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select   1 as ID,* From  ColourGroup for XML RAW))`

Comment: @RameshRajendran Interesting.  I never use AS but it should work if you  Select id=1,* from ColourGroup fpr XML RAW

Comment: @RameshRajendran Using the sample data above AS seems to work  
Select JSON=[dbo].[svf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select 1 as id,* From (at)Table For XML Raw))

Comment: I already tried the both ways.  everything is working. but only am getting error in these ways. I don't know why.

Comment: not an error. Am getting JSON object instead JSON Array while using `as` or `id=1`. @John

Comment: @RameshRajendran I see now.  The first field in your select is the ENTITY within the EAV.  This must be distinct.  If you run the sample where ID is distinct you will get an array

Comment: I solved it. **You should pass the first columns always be a primary column**. If I use `as` key word after the`*`, then it's working fine. the code now `Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select *,1 as Id From ColourGroup for XML RAW))`

Comment: Simple suggestion that I've implemented myself, add an argument to force the results when `@IncludeHead = 0` to be presented as a list (surrounded by square brackets) even if just one single result is returned

Comment: What if I want to have child json within this json?

Comment: Note, this doesn't handle null values

Comment: @MikeCole I suspect if you add >>>  FOR XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL   <<< you won't get a NULL value but you should get an empty string, but that tends to be a slippery slope... is it truly null or just an empty string.

Answer (score 7):

The following should create the JSON array for just about any data set.  However, I have not created a way to convert bit to true/false yet.

Just one point to consider: The FIRST column in the initial SELECT has to be the Primary Key which is equates to the ENTITY field.  In this case, `Select * from @User for XML RAW` ... ID is the Entity and just so happens to be the first field in the table

As far as performance, 500 records with 19 fields creates a JSON string 191,987 bytes in 0.694 seconds (50 records in 0.098 seconds)

Consider the following:

```
Declare @User table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50),LastOn DateTime)
Insert into @User values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com','2016-10-05 17:32:41.903'),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com','2016-10-05 08:25:18.203')

Declare @XML   xml = (Select * From @User  for XML RAW)
Declare @JSON  varchar(max) = ''

;with cteEAV as (
      Select RowNr     = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
            ,Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(100)')
            ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
            ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
       From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
       Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt) )
     ,cteBld as (
      Select *
            ,NewRow = IIF(Lag(Entity,1)  over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,'',',{')
            ,EndRow = IIF(Lead(Entity,1) over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,',','}')
            ,JSON   = Concat('"',Attribute,'":','"',Value,'"')
       From  cteEAV )
Select @JSON = @JSON+NewRow+JSON+EndRow
 From  cteBld 

Select '['+Stuff(@JSON,1,1,'')+']'
```

**Returns**

```
[{"ID":1, "Active":1, "First_Name":"John", "Last_Name":"Smith", "EMail":"john.smith@email.com", "LastOn":"2016-10-05T17:32:41.903", "TotalSales":25569.0000} ,{"ID":2, "Active":0, "First_Name":"Jane", "Last_Name":"Doe", "EMail":"jane.doe@email.com", "LastOn":"2016-10-05T08:25:18.203", "TotalSales":22888.0000}]
```

**A more readable version**

[image]

**cteEAV will dynamically unpivot the data and generate the following:**

[image]

**cteBLD will extend and add flags New/End Row**
[image]

**The Final Select**

This will put it all together and generate one final string which can be wrapped or nested as you please.