# How to generate json from two tables

Tags: json, sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2008. I have to manually create JSON with data from two tables which are related by one-to-many relationship. So, I have to first get a row from table A and then get all the rows from table B corresponding to the row from table A and use concatenation to generate JSON. I have done this for data from a single table. I am thinking of creating a temp table and put the table A data first. Then loop through and get data from table B and concatenate them into JSON. There may be a better way of doing it. Any lead will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use this UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883243/how-to-make-json-from-sql-query-in-ms-sql-2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use FOR JSON to achieve this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempA;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempB;

Create TABLE #tempA(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ValueOfA VARCHAR(50))
Create TABLE #tempB(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ValueOfB VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #tempA VALUES ('Testing A1'), ('Testing A2'), ('Testing A3'), ('Testing A4'), ('Testing A5')
INSERT INTO #tempB VALUES ('Testing B1'), ('Testing B2'), ('Testing B3'), ('Testing B4'), ('Testing B5')

SELECT a.ID as 'ID', a.ValueOfA as 'A', b.ValueOfB as 'B'
FROM #tempA a
INNER JOIN #tempB b ON a.ID = b.ID
FOR JSON PATH
```