# How can I generate JSON results in older SQL Server versions?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table which contains data similar to this. I want to get `ItemNames` in JSON format as I have mentioned in the expected output below.

```
OrderId         CustomerId    ItemId        ItemName
-------         ----------    ------        ---------
 1                   14          6            Apples
 2                   14          7            Oranges
 3                   23         10            Mangoes
```

Expected output:

```
 ResultId      CustomerId           OrderedItems
 --------      ----------           ---------------------------------------
    1              14              [{"ItemId":6,"ItemName":"Apples"},{"ItemId":7,"ItemName":"Oranges"}]
    2              23              [{"ItemId":10,"ItemName":"Mangoes"}]
```

Note: I know in latest SQL Server, there are functions `FOR JSON` to convert to JSON format but it won't work in older SQL versions. Therefore, I am expecting the answer which should work on previous versions as well.

Comment: It works on all *supported* SQL Server versions.

Comment: For older versions, you should probably perform the serialization step on the client. Older versions don't have `STRING_AGG` either, which makes concatenating strings a real problem. In general, SQL, the language, is *not* a good choice for text manipulation

Comment: 2012 & 2014 are still supported, @PanagiotisKanavos , just they're in extended support. Personally, if you do need to create JSON data is 2014 or prior, you'll likely want a CLR function.

Comment: There are [answers on SO that will give you various hacky ways of producing JSON on earlier versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39883243/4137916), by suitably butchering XML for example, but all of these that don't just use CLR functions to delegate suffer from potential problems with things like escaping (for which JSON has different rules than XML). Not recommended unless you really have no way of eating the rowset in its native form and producing the JSON client-side.

Comment: Another option: `FOR XML`. Use newtonsoft at the client to convert xml to JSON

Comment: @JeroenMostert  "hacky" may be a little strong, but I appreciate the consideration.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: no personal slight intended -- sometimes you have to work with what you have to work with. It remains true that a full-fledged, correct implementation in T-SQL for producing JSON is really beyond the abilities of the language to do well (in versions lacking the native support). A solution that works on all data sets also needs the equivalent of `STRING_ESCAPE`, for example.

Comment: @JeroenMostert None taken.  It made me chuckle.  You are correct, it is not ideal and has risks.   In my little head it was a necessary evil.

Comment: I have an answer of this question. please, wait for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something based on this?

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [OrderID] INT
   ,[CustomerID] INT
   ,[ItemID] INT
   ,[ItemName] NVARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([OrderID], [CustomerID], [ItemID], [ItemName])
VALUES (1, 14, 6, 'Apples')
      ,(2, 14, 7, 'Oranges')
      ,(3, 23, 10, 'Mangoes');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [CustomerID]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.[CustomerID]) AS ResultId      
      ,*
FROM DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT '[' + STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + CONCAT('{"ItemId":', [ItemID],',"ItemName":"', [ItemName],'"}')
            FROM @DataSource
            WHERE [CustomerID] = DS.[CustomerID]
            ORDER BY [ItemID]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    ) + ']'
) Items ([OrderedItems]);
```

[image]