# Return JSON as a Treeview from parent-child SQL table

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to return the table with paren-child hierarchy as a treeview json.
Googling gives vague code that seems way too complicated for this, or making something like this is supposed to be complicated?
Using .NET Web Api with Dapper. I've never worked with Dapper properly before, but seems like doing this with Entity Framework is easier. Or perhaps my models and table structures are wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE Regions (
RegionId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
RegionName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
FK_RegionParentId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Regions(RegionId)
);
```

Model of this table

```
    public class Region
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Region> FK_ParentId { get; set; }

}

[
{
    "regionId": 1,
    "regionName": "Europe",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 2,
    "regionName": "Asia",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 3,
    "regionName": "Africa",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 4,
    "regionName": "France",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 5,
    "regionName": "India",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 6,
    "regionName": "China",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 7,
    "regionName": "Zimbabwe",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 8,
    "regionName": "Hong Kong",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 9,
    "regionName": "Beijing",
    "fK_ParentId": null
},
{
    "regionId": 10,
    "regionName": "Shanghai",
    "fK_ParentId": null
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate nested nth level JSON SQL Server using recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053148/generate-nested-nth-level-json-sql-server-using-recursive-cte)

Comment: @Charlieface The function from this link works and I also managed to make my table work with it in dbfiddle, but I am using SQL Server 14 and in SQL Management Studio it is throwing me an errors.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2014? Yes that does not have JSON support, however there are [various workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883243/how-to-make-json-from-sql-query-in-ms-sql-2014/39946937). I strongly suggest you upgrade to a version that is still in support, such as 2017 or 2019. Please add a link to your fiddle. Another option is to just do it in C# using Newtonsoft or JsonSerializer

Comment: @Charlieface No I rechecked and my version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64). Here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c107da82064dc98b933937b9b2c983a 
It would be much better if  did it in the SQL though. Your script seems to be very elegant so I'd like to use it instead.

Comment: You can't use `WITH INLINE = ON` in 2017, so remove that. Then it should all work

Comment: @Charlieface Ok it works in SQL Management Studio, but how can I make it work in .NET Web API returning this as an api endpoint? I know that this function creates a new table, but simply querying "SELECT dbo.GetJson(NULL)" returns empty table in  Postman.

Comment: I don't know I'm not really familiar with Postman. Perhaps it needs a column alias `SELECT dbo.GetJson(NULL) AS Json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://medium.com/dapper-net/one-to-many-mapping-with-dapper-55ae6a65cfd4 Try this. Looks like your trying to produce a Json object representing a one to many relationship. I would certainly make those naming conventions less confusing. Like Continent and Country for the table names.